# How to enable spell check in Vim for JSON files?

Tags: vim

I am wondering how to enable spell check in Vim for JSON files?
I tried: `set spell` but no effect of highlighting, no spell checking in JSON appears.
Any suggestions what is causing issue?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does spell checking work for other (e.g. plain text) buffers? You also need to set a `'spelllang'` language (e.g. `en_us`).

The `syntax/json.vim` script doesn't mark any syntax groups for spell checking. As JSON is basically a format for defining data structures, it's also not clear which parts should be checked; this depends a lot on the particular data. Therefore, Vim will by default check *all* words in a JSON document. Whether that's useful depends on you.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that something wrong with my plugins or configs, but I am not sure with which one. I have plenty of them, I need to check one by one.